# Swing вывод массива

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет! В книге Якова Файна есть задание:

"Модифицируйте класс Calculator.java так, чтобы все кнопки с цифрами хранились в массиве с десятью элементами, который должен быть объявлен вот так:
Buttons[] numButtons= new Buttons[10];
Замените 10 строк кода, которые начинаются с button0=new JButton("0"); циклом, который создаёт кнопки и добавляет их в массив."

Исходный код программы:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class Calculator {
// Объявление всех компонентов калькулятора.
JPanel windowContent;
JTextField displayField;
JButton button0;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JButton button5;
JButton button6;
JButton button7;
JButton button8;
JButton button9;
JButton buttonPoint;
JButton buttonEqual;
JPanel p1;
 // В конструкторе создаются все компоненты
 // и добавляются на фрейм с помощью комбинации
 // Borderlayout и Gridlayout
 Calculator(){
 windowContent= new JPanel();
// Задаём схему для этой панели
 BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
 windowContent.setLayout(bl);
 // Создаём и отображаем поле
 // Добавляем его в Северную область окна
displayField = new JTextField(30);
 windowContent.add("North",displayField);
 // Создаём кнопки, используя конструктор
 // класса JButton, который принимает текст
 // кнопки в качестве параметра
 button0=new JButton("0");
 button1=new JButton("1");
 button2=new JButton("2");
 button3=new JButton("3");
 button4=new JButton("4");
 button5=new JButton("5");
 button6=new JButton("6");
 button7=new JButton("7");
 button8=new JButton("8");
 button9=new JButton("9");
 buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
 buttonEqual=new JButton("=");
 // Создаём панель с GridLayout
 // которая содержит 12 кнопок - 10 кнопок с числами
 // и кнопки с точкой и знаком равно
 p1 = new JPanel();
 GridLayout gl =new GridLayout(4,3);
 p1.setLayout(gl);
 // Добавляем кнопки на панель p1
 p1.add(button1);
 p1.add(button2);
 p1.add(button3);
 p1.add(button4);
 p1.add(button5);
 p1.add(button6);
 p1.add(button7);
 p1.add(button8);
 p1.add(button9);
 p1.add(button0);
 p1.add(buttonPoint);
 p1.add(buttonEqual);
 // Помещаем панель p1 в центральную область окна
 windowContent.add("Center",p1);
 //Создаём фрейм и задаём его основную панель
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
 frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
 // делаем размер окна достаточным
 // для того, чтобы вместить все компоненты
 frame.pack();
 // Наконец, отображаем окно
 frame.setVisible(true);
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Calculator calc = new Calculator();
 }
}
```

Вот что получилось у меня:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class Calculator {
    
    // Объявление всех компонентов калькулятора
    JButton[] numButtons;
    JPanel windowContent;
    JTextField displayField;
    JButton button10;
    JButton button11;
    JButton button12;
    JButton button13;
    JButton buttonPoint;
    JButton buttonEqual;
    JPanel p1;
    JPanel p2;
    
    
        // В конструкторе создаются все компоненты и добавляются на фрейм с помощью комбинации Borderlayout и Gridlayout
        Calculator() {          
            windowContent = new JPanel();
            
            // Задаём схему для этой панели
            BorderLayout b1 = new BorderLayout();
            windowContent.setLayout(b1);
            
            // Создаём и отображаем поле добавляем его в Северную область окна
            displayField = new JTextField(30);
            windowContent.add("North", displayField);
            

            
            // Создаём кнопки, используя конструктор класса JButton, который принимает текст кнопки в качестве параметра
            button10 = new JButton("+");
            button11 = new JButton("-");
            button12 = new JButton("/");
            button13 = new JButton("*");
            buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
            buttonEqual = new JButton("=");
            
            // Создаём панель с GridLayout которая содержит 12 кнопок - 10 кнопок с числами и кнопки с точкой и знаком равно
            p1 = new JPanel();
            GridLayout g1 = new GridLayout(4,3);
            p1.setLayout(g1);
            
            // Заменить 10 строк кода циклом, который создаёт кнопки и добавляет их в массив
            numButtons = new JButton[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < numButtons.length; i++) {
                numButtons[i] = new JButton();
                p1.add(numButtons[i]);
            }
            
            // Создаем панель +,-,/,* из домашнего задания
            p2 = new JPanel();
            GridLayout g2 = new GridLayout(4,3);
            p2.setLayout(g2);
            
            // Добавляем кнопки на панель p1
            p1.add(buttonPoint);
            p1.add(buttonEqual);
            
            // Добавляем кнопки на панель p2
            p2.add(button10);
            p2.add(button11);
            p2.add(button12);
            p2.add(button13);
            
            
            
            // Помещаем панель p1 в центральную область окна
            windowContent.add("Center", p1);
            windowContent.add("East", p2);
            
            // Создаём фрейм и задаём его основную панель
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
            frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
            
            // Делаем размер окна достаточным для того, чтобы вместить все компоненты
            frame.pack();
            
            // Наконец, отображаем окно
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        }
}
```

Сам цикл начинается со втрого примера кода со строки 58.

```
 button0=new JButton("0");
 button1=new JButton("1");
 button2=new JButton("2");
 button3=new JButton("3");
 button4=new JButton("4");
 button5=new JButton("5");
 button6=new JButton("6");
 button7=new JButton("7");
 button8=new JButton("8");
 button9=new JButton("9");

 p1.add(button1);
 p1.add(button2);
 p1.add(button3);
 p1.add(button4);
 p1.add(button5);
 p1.add(button6);
 p1.add(button7);
 p1.add(button8);
 p1.add(button9);
```

оздав массив - я объявил компоненты калькулятора
JButton[] numButtons;
numButtons = new JButton[10];

Два верхних столбца я заменил циклом for и создал переменную numButtons которой присвоен массив с присвоением результата цикла [i]
numButtons[i] = new JButton();

Во втрой столбец  добавил кнопки и как параметр прописал переменную массива с результатом цикла
p1.add(numButtons[i]);

И вот что вышло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно сам вопрос:
Все ли я правильно сделал? Никак не могу понять как на кнопки добавить цифры?
Я думал numButtons[i] = new JButton(); будет прописывать numButtons1 = new JButton("1") и т.д и будет добавлять цифры на кнопки, но этого не происходит, что я не так понял? Спасибо!

Comment: Решил в
numButtons[i] = new JButton("" +i);
добавил "" +i. Не знал что цикл добавлять нужно после кавычек, добавлял без кавычек выдавало ошибку!

Comment: в i хранится число, а нужна строка. ""+i -- просто самый лёгкий способ сделать из числа строку. Поэтому оно у вас и сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть примерно так (добавил слушатель, чтобы показать, каким образом отображать на экране нажатые клавиши: в данном случае цифры):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Calculator {
    
    private final JPanel windowContent;
    private final JTextField displayField;    
    private final JButton [] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    private final JButton buttonPoint;
    private final JButton buttonEqual;
    private final JPanel panel;
    
    private Calculator() {
        windowContent = new JPanel();
        windowContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        displayField = new JTextField(30);
        windowContent.add("North", displayField);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++) {
            int x = (i+1)%10;
            numberButtons[x] = new JButton(String.valueOf(x));
            panel.add(numberButtons[x]);
            numberButtons[x].addActionListener(e -> pressNumberButton(numberButtons[x]));
        }
        buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
        buttonEqual = new JButton("=");
        panel.add(buttonPoint);
        panel.add(buttonEqual);
        windowContent.add("Center", panel);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    private void pressNumberButton(JButton button) {
        displayField.setText(displayField.getText()+button.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
    
}
```